# Issues installing Drake locally on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drake

I am following the instructions in the textbook of the course 6.832, appendix A, on how to install Drake locally on Linux.

All the installation steps have completed and seems to be successful. In addition, I have installed all the prerequisites as described. However, when I run the test in section 2.3

```
(python -c 'import pydrake; print(pydrake.__file__)')
```

I have experienced several errors.

It seems that it is trying to access older version of several `lib***.so` files than what I have.

F.eks: Pydrake tried to include libgfortran.so.3, when I only have libgfortran.so.4 on my computer. I tried to do some "hackfixes" by using the `ln -s` command to make the terminal accept "libgfortran.so.4" as "libgfortran.so.3". But, now I ran into another error that I don't know how to solve.

It says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>     File
>   "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrake/**init**.py", line 32,
>   in     from . import common  File
>   "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrake/common/**init**.py",
>   line 3, in     from ._module_py import * ImportError:
>   /opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so:
>   undefined symbol:
>   _ZN6google8protobuf2io17CodedOutputStream28WriteVarint32FallbackToArrayEjPh

How do I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you followed section A.2.1 "download the binaries" verbatim, you would be downloading https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/drake/continuous/drake-latest-xenial.tar.gz, the package for **Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)**, which links to `libgfortran.so.3`.

Since you are on **Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)**, you would instead need to download https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/drake/continuous/drake-latest-bionic.tar.gz, which links to `libgfortran.so.4`.